# bit columns generating warnings - how can a cast in the field list affect the cardinality estimate?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, execution-plan, type-conversion, cardinality-estimates

A few days ago I had a question about warnings in the execution plan

[Type conversion in expression may affect “CardinalityEstimate” - on a computed column?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/203897/type-conversion-in-expression-may-affect-cardinalityestimate-on-a-computed-c?rq=1)

and that was solved, thanks [Paul](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1192/paul-white). Now I have another question regarding the `cardinality estimate`, this time it is caused by the `bit` data type.

I am using [sys.data_spaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-data-spaces-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [sys.indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-indexes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

to run a simple query to get some information about my indexes:

```
SELECT i.name AS index_name  
,[ObjectType] =             
  i.type_desc + 
  CAST ( CASE WHEN CAST (i.is_primary_key AS INT)  = 1 
  THEN SPACE(2)  + '     Primary Key '      ELSE '' END AS NVARCHAR(30)) + 

  CAST ( CASE WHEN i.is_unique_constraint = 1 THEN SPACE(2)  + 
  'Unique Constraint' ELSE '' END AS NVARCHAR(30))+

  CAST ( CASE WHEN i.is_unique = 1 THEN 
         CASE WHEN i.is_primary_key = 0 AND i.is_unique_constraint = 0 
              THEN SPACE(2)  + 'Unique' ELSE '' END 
         ELSE SPACE(2)  + 'Non-Unique' END AS NVARCHAR(30)) +

  CAST ( CASE WHEN i.has_filter = 1 THEN SPACE(2)  + 'Filtered' 
         ELSE '' END AS NVARCHAR(30)) +

  CAST ( CASE WHEN i.is_padded = 1 THEN SPACE(2)  + 'Padded'            
         ELSE '' END AS NVARCHAR(30))

    --,i.type_desc  
    --,is_unique  
    --,ds.type_desc AS filegroup_or_partition_scheme  
    ,ds.name AS filegroup_or_partition_scheme_name  
    ,ignore_dup_key  
    --,is_primary_key  
    ,is_unique_constraint  
    ,fill_factor  
    ,is_padded  
    --,is_disabled  
    ,allow_row_locks  
    ,allow_page_locks  
FROM sys.indexes AS i  
INNER JOIN sys.data_spaces AS ds ON i.data_space_id = ds.data_space_id  
WHERE 1=1
  AND is_hypothetical = 0 
  AND i.is_disabled = 0
  AND ds.is_system = 0  

GO
```

the query runs fine 
[image]

but somehow dealing with the `bit` columns is upsetting the execution plan, causing some warnings related to conversion:

> --Type conversion in expression (CONVERT(nvarchar(30),CASE WHEN
>   CONVERT(bit,[i].[status]&(32),0)=(1) THEN '  Primary Key ' ELSE ''
>   END,0)) may affect "CardinalityEstimate" in query plan choice,
>
> --Type conversion in expression (CONVERT(nvarchar(30),CASE WHEN CONVERT(bit,[i].[status]&(64),0)=(1) THEN '  Unique Constraint' ELSE
>   '' END,0)) may affect "CardinalityEstimate" in query plan choice,
>
> --Type conversion in expression (CONVERT(nvarchar(30),CASE WHEN CONVERT(bit,[i].[status]&(131072),0)=(1) THEN '  Filtered' ELSE ''
>   END,0)) may affect "CardinalityEstimate" in query plan choice,
>
> --Type conversion in expression (CONVERT(nvarchar(30),CASE WHEN CONVERT(bit,[i].[status]&(16),0)=(1) THEN '  Padded' ELSE '' END,0))
>   may affect "CardinalityEstimate" in query plan choice

My question(s) are:

I am dealing only with the query returning columns, should I worry about this warning?

is it related to the `bit` data type?

is there any way to change the code and get rid of this warning?

if it is only noise, can I regulate it?

Comment: I would ignore this, especially since it's being thrown by system views. Unfortunately there's no way to mute it.